# RcppParallel using References in workers

Tags: rcpp, rcpparmadillo, rcppparallel

I have been experiment with using references for speed improvements. The (not working) trivial example below, probably won't see any improvements.  However, I think by not copying the data into a separate (cost) function, should save some time for a non trivial example.

As for now I have the example in an R-project as three c++ files:

header

```
#ifndef ExampleInternal_H
#define ExampleInternal_H

namespace ExampleInternal{

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

void myfuncA(arma::rowvec &vec_in, arma::colvec& data){

  vec_in.at(1) = vec_in.at(0)*arma::accu(data);

}

struct PARALLEL_WORKER : RcppParallel::Worker{

  arma::mat &input_output;
  const arma::colvec &data_in;

  PARALLEL_WORKER(arma::mat &input_output, const arma::colvec &data_in);
  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end);
};

}

#endif
```

Function

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include "ExampleInternal.h"
using namespace ExampleInternal;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat Parallelfunc(int Len_in, const arma::colvec data_in){

  arma::mat input(Len_in, 2, arma::fill::zeros);
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Len_in; i ++){
    input.at(i, 0) =i;
    }

  ExampleInternal::PARALLEL_WORKER worker(input, data_in);
  parallelFor(0, Len_in, worker);
  return input;
}
```

Parallel Worker

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include "ExampleInternal.h"

using namespace RcppParallel;
using namespace ExampleInternal;

namespace ExampleInternal{

PARALLEL_WORKER::PARALLEL_WORKER(arma::mat &input_output, const arma::colvec &data_in) : input_output(input_output), data_in(data_in) {}
  void PARALLEL_WORKER::operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end){

    for(unsigned int k = begin; k < end; k ++){

      ExampleInternal::myfuncA(input_output.row(k), data_in);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: See the [Rcpp FAQ 5.1](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) and other references: we deal in `SEXP` object per the only interface offered by R, and the P in `SEXP` is for pointer so references (generally) buy you very little to nothing extra as only the small `SEXP` objects are on the heap.

Comment: Ok, it seems straight forward that R(originating) objects are already used through a pointer and would offer little benefit.  Would this extend to objects generated on the c++ side of things?